# Get the "name" of a <input> and generate a POST with it in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to test a process in a website I can't control. This page consist of 6 forms and the process is just sending POST with the fields needed. I know how to send a POST with the fields but this form has **random name and id values**... So, in some way I need to first get the name assigned to this `<input name="thanks-for-making-my-life-randomly-easy" />` (6 in each page) and then make a POST with it.

I've seen that there is extractors for CSS/jQuery or even XPath so I could find a way to "find" the desired input but... how I can prepare a POST request with the given names?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression extractor can help you to find it.

```
Example: 
<input name="(.+?)" />
```

Refer : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html